# How to echo the contents of a file using Sessions - PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the current code I am using:

```
<?php

    $blacklist = array("one.jps", "two.txt", "four.html");
    $files = array_diff(glob("*.*"), $blacklist);

    foreach($files as $file)
        echo "<div class='post'><a href='" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?file=" . $file . "'><p>" . $file . "</p></a></div>";


    if(!empty($_GET["file"]) && !in_array($_GET["file"], $blacklist) && file_exists($_GET["file"])) 
        $thesource = htmlentities(file_get_contents($_GET["file"]));

?>

<textarea rows="40" cols="100" placeholder="Source code of file" class="source"><?php if(!empty($thesource))echo $thesource; ?></textarea>
```

What happens here is that all the files contained within the directory are echoed out:

```
<a class='okok' href='index.php?file=$file'>$file</a>*
```

- Where $file is the name of the file that is being echoed out.

When you click on any of the links, the contents within that file are displayed into a textarea. This works perfectly but however the page refreshes and you are sent to the following URL:

```
http://example.com/index.php?file=bob.html *
```

The *file=* won't always be bob.html, it depends on which link you clicked on.

This means that the user can simply edit the URL and change 'bob.html' to something like 'index.php' and therefore gain access to all PHP code.

How would I rewrite this code so that the URL isn't affected - I believe I should be using sessions but how would I do so

Comment: As far as I know, a user can never see the PHP code. If the PHP code in 'index.php' doesn't echo anything, your users will just see an empty page.

Comment: @Goudgeld1 In short, when the user clicks on one of the links (links of each and every file in the directory), it will display **all** of the contents on that file into the textarea, including PHP code. This is because the variable is written into the URL but however, I am trying to find another way to do this

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish this.  1 - whitelist files that users can edit.  2 - blacklist files that users cannot edit 3 - blacklist file extensions that are never allowed to be read.

Answer (score 0):

You can add another condition to your if statement. We need to get the filename from url and check whether its ending with "php". Below should do the trick

```
//checking file type by exploding the variable  
$fileType = end(explode(".", $_GET["file"]));
    if( $fileType != "php" && !empty($_GET["file"]) && !in_array($_GET["file"], $blacklist) && file_exists($_GET["file"])) {
```

Comment: If you have many more extensions to check you can reverse the logic.

`$allowedExtensions = array("html", "txt", "xml");
$fileType = end(explode(".", $_GET["file"]));
if( in_array($fileType, $allowedExtensions ) ){
  // it is an allowed file
}`

Comment: Thanks but the user can still enter into the URL. For example, if the directory is called *test*, the user can enter '../index.html' into the URL and see the contents of the website's homepage, how would I prevent this? Though, I believe storing the variables into a session variable would be much more safer instead of into the URL